# Recommended database approach for website galleries and images

Tags: database, laravel, schema

I'm creating the schema for a website which will have images and an object type of `post`, which an image may belong to. So my image database can look like this:

```
# 'Image' table
----------------
id
name
url
post_id
```

Then, for each post, I can grab its image. But:

- two posts can never share an image
- if I add another object type of `page`, I'd have to ensure they never have the same `id`.

So I figure a good start is to just remove the `post_id` field from the image as its more trouble than its worth. What is the best solution for this kind of manyToMany issue? At the moment I am thinking of having an in between table:

```
# 'Gallery' pivot table
------------------------
id
object_type [post or page]
object_id
image_id
```

Now `posts` and `pages` can have multiple `images`. I just whip through this to grab all the associated images for the object type. Is this right? If it makes any difference, I am using the **Laravel** framework. I'm building quite a large app and am conscious that if I get this wrong early on it could really bite me later.

Comment: I'd work with polymorphic relationships so you have a table with both posts and pages. then a simple foreign key on the image is enough. I don't know how your page and posts model look like though. Are they similar in some parts? or completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still answered your question :-)
I´d go with many to many relationships - so a pivot table is needed.

there is a convention that the pivot table-name is named after their models its connecting (in alphabetical order). So for example in your case your pivot-table would look like:

```
table: image_post
------------------------
id  |  image_id  |  post_id
```

check the documentatin for further information: [many-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

eager loading is also an interesting part to read:
[eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

e.g. querying a specific post and all its images:

```
$post = Post::with( 'images' )->find($id);
```